# How to control Datasource loop in Soap UI

Tags: soap

I am having two test case in the Soap UI and one Data driven excel sheet which contains 10 rows.

**Test Case 1:**

1. DataSource
2. Register consumer request
3. Take consumer id.

**Test Case 2:**

1) Run TEST CASE 1  (which means register consumer using RUN TEST CASE option)
2) data source card Details 
3) card details request.
4) Data source loop

**Data sheet xls.**

personal details row1
card details row 1


personal details row2
card details row 2

My requirement when i run the second test case take 1st row for the register details and card details and second row register details and card details etc.....

Now My problem. when run the second test case.i am always getting register details from the first row only but getting card details correctly...running 10 times with the row 1 register details

So i thought of adding Data Source loop in the test case 1.

This time test case 1 is running 10 time and once 10 row is finished only 2nd test case is proceeded.

If any one give me the solution.. that would be great help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I would say that you have to do it in just one TestCase.

Did you already had a look at the DataSource tutorial on the soapUI page: http://soapui.org/Data-Driven-Testing/functional-tests.html